# RemoteConnection to SQL server2008 express failed on Visual Studio

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, connection, sql-server-express

After 2 Days of search i still didnt find an answer.

**Situation:**

**Server:** 
SQL Server 2008 Express installed on RemoteServer
TCP/IP: *Enabled on port 1433*
Named Pipes: *Enabled* 
Database: *ConDB.mdf (attached to server)*

**Workstation:**
Microsoft Management Studio: ***Connection to database works***

> Servertype: Databasemodul 
>   Servername: MTTC5020\SQLEXPRESS,1433
>   
>  Authentifcation: SQL
>   Server-Authentification 
>  Username:
>   testuser
>  Password: 1234

**Visual Studio 2010 Express:**

> Error on Database Explorer: *SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error
>   Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified*

Same Error Through Connection via Appconfig and connectionstring:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ContainerDB.My.MySettings.ConDBConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=MTTC5020\SQLEXPRESS,1433;Initial Catalog=ConDB.mdf;User ID=testuser;Password=1234;Integrated Security=false"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I also tried many other connectionstrings (Via IP / AttachedDBFileName / etc.)

I also tried everything here: [MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2007/05/13/sql-network-interfaces-error-26-error-locating-server-instance-specified.aspx) 
 
 portcheck through SQLCMD -U testuser -P 1234 -S MTTC5020\SQLEXPRESS,1433 works aswell 
 Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I now found the issue. 
The connectionstring for the dbml is not only stored in the .config file.

checkout the workaround for this at:
[LINQ to SQL Connection Strings](http://www.toplinestrategies.com/dotneters/uncategorized/linq-to-sql-connection-strings/?lang=en)

Answer (score 0):

Because by default express editions are installed as named instances, SQL Server on the remote machine needs to be allowed in firewall, not only the port, but the service, because named instances probably will change the port from time to time. Check this post, hope this helps blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/

Comment: Locally i also tried (during the development) and everything worked fine. But i also read that an access to SQLEXPRESS servers works a little bit more complicated. And if i can connect the Management Studio to the remote database, i should be able to do this with the studio. or am i wrong?

Comment: Sorry for the confusing answer, i was wrong. You can connect to a Express instance. But because by default express editions are installed as named instances, SQL Server on the remote machine needs to be allowed in firewall, not only the port, but the service, because named instances probably will change the port from time to time. Check this post, hope this helps http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2005/05/05/415084.aspx

Comment: this post i also found. and the portcheck through SQLCMD -U testuser -P 1234 -S MTTC5020\SQLEXPRESS,1433 is also success. so the firewall cant be the problem. also the port is static and not dynamic